# Google Calendar api return bad End Date when event is all day

Tags: ios, date, google-calendar-api

This only occurs when an event is all day. In the next picture I select to the start date 04/02/2016 and 02/06/2016 to the end date for all day.

[image]

But when I check this via the API. This is the answer that gives me.

[image]

For the end date returns a day after the specified. But this works for all events that have no all selected day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually working as intended. I agree wholeheartedly to look @luc's response.

For all-day event:

> All day dates should actually be entered with end date of next day.